# Loops and conditionals in TASM Assembly 8086 DOS

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, x86-16, conditional-statements

I want to run this loop with a conditional at the end in this fashion

```
mov cx, 10
mov di, 0

loop:

...

inc di
dec cx

cmp di, 5
jne loop

...     

jnz loop
```

but it seems like it won't work unless I decrement cx immediately before

```
jnz loop
```

this is preventing me from decrementing cx each time that `di != 5`. 
I think I am misunderstanding the proper use of cx

Answer (score 2):

`JNZ` jumps if the [zero flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) is clear. There are many x86 instructions that will modify the zero flag besides `DEC`.

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
cmp di, 5
je no_dec
dec cx      ; decrement CX when di != 5
no_dec:
...
jncxz loop  ; jump if CX != 0
            ; if JNCXZ isn't supported on the target CPU you could
            ; replace it with CMP CX,0 / JNZ loop
```

Btw, `LOOP` is a poor choice for a label name since `LOOP` is an instruction on x86. In fact, you can replace code like this:

```
dec cx
jnz label
```

with

```
loop label  ; decrements CX and jumps if not zero
```

Comment: if put dec cx at the end, then cx doesn't get decremented when the jne condition is met, that's my problem

Comment: How about the `loopnz` instruction?

Comment: @Powerslave: `loopnz` always decrements `CX`. The OP only wanted to decrement `CX` given that a certain condition was true.

Comment: @Michael That wasn't mentioned in the question nor is it reflected by the code snippet provided with the question. Still it seems to me that `CX` is to be decremented unconditionally to which the `loop` instruction applies. Also, conditionality can be easily implemented with `loopz` or `loopnz` provided a `cmp` sets the zero flag if `CX` should not be decremented and a `jz` follows the `loopnz` immediately - or the other way around with `loopz` (that's what they're for).

Comment: @Powerslave: It's mentioned in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @Michael One of us for sure misunderstood. In my interpretation it does not mean that he/she only wants to decrement when `DI != 5`, but rather the problem keeps him/her from decrementing `CX` *whenever* `DI != 5` (given that the execution path does not include the `DEC CX` line if it's put after the `JNE`) although it meant to be decremented undconditionally, with each iteration. Still, the conditional `loopz`/`loopnz` pair would solve the issue of conditional looping (and decrementing `CX`)

Answer (score 0):

```
xor di,di
mov cx,10
_theLoop:
    ; ...
    inc di    ; I wonder why are you incrementing DI manually...
    cmp di,5
    ja _done
    loop _theLoop
_done:
```